# How to check whether file exists in zip file using dotnetzip

Tags: c#, compression, dotnetzip

I am creating zip using dotnetzip library.

But I don't know how to check if a file exists in the zip. If the file exists then I will update the file with path.

```
    public void makezip(string flname)
   {
      string  fln =flname;
        string curFile = @"d:\crs.zip";
        if (File.Exists(curFile))
        {
                ZipFile zipfl = ZipFile.Read(@"D:\crs.zip");
            var result = zipfl.Any(entry => entry.FileName.EndsWith(@fln));
            if (result == true) {
                zipfl.UpdateFile(@fln);
                }else{
                  zipfl.AddFile(@fln);
                }
            zipfl.Save(@"d:\crs.zip");
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                ZipFile zipfl = new ZipFile();

                var result = zipfl.Any(entry => entry.FileName.EndsWith(@fln));
                if (result == true)
                {
                  zipfl.AddFile(@fln);
                }
                zipfl.Save(@"d:\crs.zip");
            }catch {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Zip File");

            }}}
```

Comment: code added, im trying to do that

Comment: Which concrete example, which it's wrong?

Comment: I am calling this function through a loop. and passing file name with path. I am getting error "An Item with the same key has already been added"

Comment: Could you debug and show which case this happens, I cannot guess like this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> How to check whether file exists in zip file?

Just use LINQ `Any`, assume you have input zip file `input.zip`, to check whether `input.zip` contains `input.txt`:

```
 var zipFile = ZipFile.Read(@"C:\input.zip");
 var result = zipFile.Any(entry => entry.FileName.EndsWith("input.txt"));
```

Comment: +1; one word of caution though: if I am not mistaken, the `FileEntry.FileName` may contain (part of) a directory path as well, see [here](http://dotnetzip.herobo.com/DNZHelp/html/913abfd3-bbc6-803c-858b-f53dfb008e55.htm).

Comment: @AndersGustafsson: thanks, I have run this code, it does not containe dir path

Comment: How can i check if file has folder information like c:\ab\input.txt

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have changed my code with that. I m not able to search a file with path.

Comment: zipFile.Any(entry => entry.FileName.Equals(directory + @"/" + "input.txt"))

will search with directory information, as you might have a file with the same name or different name but ending with "input.txt" and your code will think it has already been added.

Answer (score 6):

(This is not dotnetzip but will get the job done.)

Requires: `using System.IO.Compression;`

Assembly: System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll

```
public static bool ZipHasFile(string fileFullName, string zipFullPath)
{
    using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipFullPath))  //safer than accepted answer
    {
        foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
        {
            if (entry.FullName.EndsWith(fileFullName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Example call: `var exists = ZipHelper.ZipHasFile(@"zipTest.txt", @"C:\Users\...\Desktop\zipTest.zip");`

Comment: Be mindful of unzipping files that were compressed using a Mac.  Those .zips might contain a subdirectory, "_MACOSX".  I ignore those by testing for Contains("_MACOSX") first and continuing.